# DataSourceLoader.Load Thrown exception "Failed to parse query"

Tags: ignite, devextreme

I am using Devextreme loadoptions with Ignite CacheQueryable it is working fine with Grid get all data request but throwing exception when I select filter on grid's column.

"Message": "42000: Failed to parse query. Column "_T0.I0" not found; SQL statement: select count (_T0.*) , _T0.I0 from "Data".ABC as _T0 group by (_T0.FILENAME) order by (_T0.I0) asc limit ? [42122-197]".

Comment: Can you provide more details, or a reproducer project that I can run? Either DevExtreme is generating an incorrect query, or Ignite LINQ provider is missing something. I wonder where `_T0.I0` comes from, is this in your data source?

Comment: I am passing Iqueryable to  DataSourceLoader.Load(queryable, loadOptions); and it is throwing error. the error is basically with this _T0.I0 . When grouping it is mentioning correct column name which is _T0.FILENAME but when its selecting that column it is using alias which it didn't give to a column "select count (_T0.*) , _T0.I0"

Comment: I see, but we need more details to understand the problem. Source code, reproducer project.

Comment: Hello @PavelTupitsyn kindly see the sample source code here : https://wetransfer.com/downloads/d8ad30a4bb0bc956c057a4f420cefade20221006153202/0bfd55

Comment: Here is the HttpGet request to produce error : https://localhost:44397/api/Home/GetAllData?skip=0&take=20&group=[{"selector":"FILENAME","isExpanded":false}]&select=["FILENAME"]

Comment: Thanks, I could reproduce it. Unfortunately, grouping like this is not currently supported in Ignite.

Comment: @PavelTupitsyn Thanks for the clarification, I am wondering how much time it will take to fix.

Comment: Hey @PavelTupitsyn is there any update on this? I can see IGNITE-17842 is still open. What's the expected resolution version for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a bug in Ignite, I've filed a ticket: [IGNITE-17842](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/IGNITE-17842).

Devextreme generates the following expression:

```cs
            queryable
                .GroupBy(obj => new { I0 = obj.Filename })
                .OrderBy(g => g.Key.I0)
                .Select(g => new { I0 = g.Count(), I1 = g.Key.I0 })
                .Take(20);
```

The problem is `GroupBy(obj => new { I0 = obj.Filename })`, Ignite does not (yet) support grouping by an anonymous type. It would work as `GroupBy(obj => obj.Filename)`.